# FirebaseInstanceIdService.onTokenRefresh never called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented Firebase for cloud messaging :

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register

I have follow all the steps but FirebaseInstanceIdService.onTokenRefresh is never called.

the only message from firebase on the log  is :

```
FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
```

What can i do to get this token?

Comment: Did you setup the firebase sdk and generate a google-services.json and include it in your project?

Comment: Nop, thanks for this comment, i have missed this spet : https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#prerequisites

Comment: Cool. For sake of clarity, I'll just post it as a part of the answer, if that's okay :)

Comment: ok, i set up my project and i test if i have this token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup the firebase sdk and generate a google-services.json and include it in your project. As described in this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#prerequisites).

Comment: it didn't work for me. could you suggest any other things? I did all you said in this post and onTokenRefresh still not called.

Answer (score 2):

In my case uninstall and reinstall app worked

Comment: it didn't work for me. could you suggest any other things? I did all you said in this post and onTokenRefresh still not called.